# Homological algebra in PDE

Tags: soft-question, partial-differential-equations, homological-algebra, big-picture

I have been fascinated by the power and wide applicability of homological methods in algebra and topology. Because I am also interested in PDE, there arises a natural question for me.

> What is known about applications of methods from homological algebra to the analysis of solutions of PDE on domains in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: I suggest you to read Sheaves on Manifolds by M. Kashivara, P. Schapira

Comment: Thanks for the reference, but I'm especially looking for applications to PDE on open, bounded domains in real Euclidean space, not on manifolds.

Comment: Isn't such a domain a manifold?

Comment: But not really interesting as a manifold, is it?

Comment: This is probably somewhat irrelevant, but there is an algebrization (or rather algebro-geometrization) of the idea of a PDE on a manifold. It is called a D-module. Then of course you can play all sorts of homological games with it.This shows up in representation theory, algebraic geometry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Homological techniques are very often seen in the literatures of PDE treated from a differential geometrical point of view. An extensive overview can be found in:
[Homological methods in equations of  mathematical physics](http://arxiv.org/abs/math.DG/9808130). Also I recommend one of my favorite book here: [The Geometry of Physics: An Introduction](http://books.google.com/books?id=2iq2EGNgX24C&printsec=frontcover&dq=editions%3aoQh7ihV9g44C&source=bl&ots=kIzM7JMFzt&sig=G8s-H9j8ljNDiBuqlvfv7eyhJMY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=65N9UK3JK-f10gH444HgBg&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Theodore Frankel. Some simple google-fu gives me a recent book also: [Cohomological Analysis of Partial Differential Equations and Secondary Calculus](http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=MMONO-204).

I am working on computational physics, and the methodologies arised from de Rham cohomology have been used extensively in construction of the finite element spaces for equations in electromagnetism: [Finite element exterior calculus, homological techniques, and applications](http://www.ima.umn.edu/~arnold/papers/acta.pdf). Mostly people in my field are interested in solving the Hodge Laplacian acting on a $k$-form(magnetic flux or electric field).

Answer (score 8):

You might be interested in reading Chang's "Infinite Dimensional Morse Theory" or Jost's "Riemannian Geometry and Geometric Analysis". Moreover, I guess it would be useful to give you an example: there is a result due to Bahri and Coron that states as follows: if $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$, $N\ge 3$ is a smooth bounded domain, you can find a solution of

$$\begin{cases}-\Delta u = u^{\frac{N+2}{N-2}}&\text{in }\Omega\\ u > 0 & \text{in }\Omega\\ u = 0&\text{on }\partial \Omega,\end{cases}$$

provided that the domain $\Omega$ is "topologically nontrivial", that is if the homology group $H_q(\Omega, \mathbb{Z}_2) \ne 0$ for some $q > 0$.
Of course, there are a lot of more recent works in the study of pdes which involves techniques from algebraic topology.