Homological Algebra for Analysis
While studying differential forms, I encountered some concepts from homological algebra, such as (co)chain complexes, de Rham cohomology, pullbacks, and others. Is it reasonable to study the basics of homological algebra to gain a better understanding of analysis (similar to how (multi)linear algebra significantly aids in understanding analysis)?
If so, I would appreciate a recommendation for a suitable crash course.

Yes, it'll definitely be easier to understand that stuff if you know some homological algebra. I don't know any really good references. Weibel's Introduction to Homological Algebra is a common recommendation but it has an unfortunate reputation for being full of mistakes that make it hard to read (https://www.math.umd.edu/~jmr/602/bookerrors.pdf).

Unlike some basic multi-linear algebra, homological algebra is not really needed for analysis. You learn one example of a (co)chain complex and if you were to become an analyst, there is a good chance that you will never meet another one in your life. You will be better served studying functional analysis, Sobolev spaces, etc.

Somewhat related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214883/homological-algebra-in-pde, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/212799/soft-reference-suggested-read-homological-algebraic-techniques-in-pdes

If you really want to learn where homological algebra meets analysis, read the classic Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology by Bott and Tu.
